# Getting literal expression value with OR operators instead of true or false in PHP

Tags: php

In Javascript, we can conveniently get one of the various options that is offered in `||` operator. For example:

```
console.log('a' || '' || 0); // Yields 'a'
console.log(0 || 'b' || 'a'); // Yields 'b'
```

Those results above can easily be assigned to a variable like this:

`let test = 'a' || '' || 0;`

In PHP, though, when I try this:

`$test = 'a' || '' || 0;` gives me a `$test = 1`, with `1` meaning `true`. Is there a way in PHP to get the literal value of the expression which caused it to yield `true`?

Comment: See the user-contributed notes of [PHP's logical operators page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Comment: @Vulcan It seems like the user-contributed notes are only dealing with two values to compare. When it becomes three or more, won't I have to use nested ternary operators (which I recall reading somewhere is bad practice)?

Comment: `||` doesn’t return `1`, it always returns a Boolean; which may be *printed* as `1` in the case of `true`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) for this purpose, e.g.

```
$test = 'a' ?: '' ?: 0;
var_dump($test);
> string(1) "a"

$test2 = 0 ?: 'b' ?: 'a';
var_dump($test2);
> string(1) "b"
```

There is also null coalescing operator (??) but it takes the second value only if the first is null, so e.g. `0 ?? 'a'` will take 0 because it's not null.

Comment: THIS is seriously good. The null-coalescing operator `??` is really good too, though. I take your answer, thank you :-)

Comment: A link to the manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php "Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise."

Comment: @RichardW the null coalesing operator won't work for `$test2 = 0 ?? 'b' ?? 'a';` as 0 is not null, the expression will return 0, not 'b'

Comment: @Nick I see, thank you for pointing that out. The Elvis operator is better in my case, then. I think that the answerer should add that to the answer so other visitors may get better insights in regard to this topic.

Comment: @RichardW I've updated my answer about null coalescing operator as well.

Answer (score 1):

Per some user-contributed comments on [PHP's logical operators page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), you can use the ternary operator:

```
$test = $a ? $a : ($b ? $b : 'default')
```

Or if you're running PHP 7+ and you only need to pass over null variables (rather than falsy variables) you can use the null-coalescing operator `??`:

```
$test = $a ?? $b ?? 'default'
```

Comment: I read somewhere (I really can't recall where) that using nested ternary operators is bad, though. It looks rather bulky for a one line code, but thank you for the null-coalescing operator, it's very clean.

Comment: Since PHP 5.3, you could also use the "elvis operator": `$test = $a ?: $b ?: 'default';`

Comment: I'd shy away from the nested ternary operators - but elvis `?:` or null-coalescing `??` operators are quite good.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I didn't know about the elvis operator but I would say that's the cleanest way of doing this.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I believe I note that it doesn't check falsiness in my answer but maybe I could be more clear?

Comment: Correct, nested ternary operators (more probably referred to as the conditional operator) is bad, especially within PHP as it behaves differently from other languages.  For example `echo true?'yay':true?'doh':'doh';` echos `doh` rather than what many would expect to be `yay`. But if you use it with parenthesis, be my guest as then it's clear the author knew the order it was executing.
`echo true?'yay':(true?'doh':'doh');` will yield the expected `yay` as it does in other languages such as JavaScript.

Comment: @Vulcan - Nah. It's rather me that needs to be more observant of what you've written. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> PHP's boolean operators *always* return a boolean value... as opposed
>   to other languages that return the value of the last evaluated
>   expression.

For example:

```
$a = 0 || 'avacado';
print "A: $a\n";
```

will print:

```
A: 1
```

in PHP -- as opposed to printing "A: avacado" as it would in a language like Perl or JavaScript.

This means you can't use the '||' operator to set a default value:

```
$a = $fruit || 'apple';
```

instead, you have to use the '?:' [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:):

```
$a = ($fruit ? $fruit : 'apple');
```

> if you're using PHP 7+ then you can user null-coalescing operator **??:** too.

```
<?php
// Fetches the value of $_GET['user'] and returns 'nobody'
// if it does not exist.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
// This is equivalent to:
$username = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'nobody';

// Coalescing can be chained: this will return the first
// defined value out of $_GET['user'], $_POST['user'], and
// 'nobody'.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? $_POST['user'] ?? 'nobody';
?>
```

For more information, you can refer to this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php). 
For null coalescing operator use this

[link](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)

.

Comment: True, but read the above. They managed to return the values of the expression.

Comment: @RichardW I am saying you have to use another operator to do so.

Comment: I see. In your original answer, you didn't include the null-coalescing operator though.

Comment: @RichardW I forgot to add. added now you can check